# Expo can't change background color of container

Tags: react-native, expo, background-color

As you can see I tried changing the background color with styles, forcing light mode, and changing the background color in app.json to no effect. When I inspect the background in the expo app it says that the background color is white but it clearly isn't.

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myProject",
    "slug": "myProject",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

during runtime telling me that background color is white but it actually isn't:
[image: showing that background is set to white but in reality the background is black]

Comment: Same here. Still got no solution

Answer (score 3):

If you use <Stack.Navigator ...

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ contentStyle:{backgroundColor: "white"} }}> ...
```